# How to set angularjs model value calculated from other two number fields

Tags: angularjs

Hi I am currently working on one AngularJS ionic app but facing a problem in settings up model value in the view.
It a simple form with fields defined.

```
<input type="number" ng-model="form.field1" />
<input type="number" ng-model="form.field2" ng-change="count=form.field1+form.field2" />    
<input type="number" ng-model="form.field3" ng-init="form.field3=count" ng-value="count"/>
```

On third field I can see the value displayed but when submit to server it had "0" not the counted value.

In the controller I had

```
$scope.form={};
```

Any help appreciated, new to AngularJS.

Comment: Could you post your code on here, or use pastebin/jsfiddle etc so we can see it please? Thanks

Comment: Hi just posted.

Comment: I tried this method but no luck $scope.count = 0.00;
      $scope.addNumbers = function (b1, b2) {
          
          if (b1 !== null && b2 !== null)
          {
              $scope.count = b1 + b2;
              $scope.form.Total.$setViewValue('$scope.count');
              angular.element('#Total').controller('ngModel').$render();
          }
          
      }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `ng-change`. You can just watch the variable and update it using `$scope.$watch`. You can remove `ng-init` and `ng-value` from your inputs too.

```js
   var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
    myApp.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.form={};
        $scope.$watch('form.field1 + form.field2', function (value) {
        $scope.form.field3 = value;
    });
    }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ctrl">
<input type="number" ng-model="form.field1" />
<input type="number" ng-model="form.field2"/>    
<input type="number" ng-model="form.field3"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created the `ngchange` function and post the calculation there:

```
  <input type="number" ng-model="form.field1" />
  <input type="number" ng-model="form.field2" ng-change="Myfunction()" />
  <input type="number" ng-model="form.field3" />
```

**Controller**

```
  $scope.form = {
    field1: 0,field2: 0, field3: 0
  };

  $scope.Myfunction = function() {
    $scope.form.field3 = $scope.form.field1 + $scope.form.field2;
  }
```

**[Working Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/sC3c3hnVPFY0CkCxuWVj?p=preview)**

Also we don't need `count`, `ng-init` or `ng-value` now.

Comment: What if the user types on the second input and then on the first. Your answer haven't taken care of that?

Comment: The question itself haven't mentioned `ng-change` on first input so I though he requires that on second input only.

Comment: If he wants that functionality then he can add `ng-change="Myfunction()"` in first input also and it will work