# Two way binding in Angular in more than two fields

Tags: angular

So I’ve been playing around with angular and I learned about two-way binding using “ngModel”. I got this idea, but I can’t seem to implement it, would appreciate any help on this:

What I’m trying to do: So I will have an input field, that’ll take ticket prices for “Adult”, and a similar one for “Child”. I have another two input fields that’ll calculate the ticket prices based on the fixed rates. Then I want a third field where the sum of both their calculated prices is printed. I’ve tried this so far, but can't figure out what to do now. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

here’s the code:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="ticket.adult" name="adult">
<input type="text" value="{{ ticket.adult*15 }}">

<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="ticket.child" name="child">
<input type="text" value="{{ ticket.child*5 }}">


<p>Ticket Price:<!--the total price will be displayed here--></p>
```

P.S- I've declared a ticket object in its component.ts file.

Comment: An input field is used to gather... an input. The price is an **output**. Don't use an input field to display that output. Just use text. Regarding your question. You already know how to compute both prices. And you want to sum them. How do you add two numbers in JavaScript/TypeScript?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45348973/how-to-set-angularjs-model-value-calculated-from-other-two-number-fields check this out, may this help you

Comment: @JBNizet yeah I realize that, I just used the input field randomly. I know how to add two numbers in both, but the problem is how do I return it to a variable so it displays the sum. I've tried but it isn't working

Comment: Why do you think you need a variable? `{{ ticket.child*5 + ticket.adult*15 }}` is all you need. And if you don't like these multiplications being duplicated, then add methods in your component (or in the Ticket class), and call them in the view.

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you! I'll try and see if it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this works:

```
get sum(): number {
  // calculate your price with your formula here, 
  return this.ticket.adult*15 + this.ticket.child*5;
}
```

And in your template:

```
<p>Ticket Price: {{sum}}</p>
```

In your .ts file, you can access the `sum` by just calling `this.sum`

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lmjyts?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: This will not return the total, also it should be {{sum()}} , controller ?

Comment: @Sajeetharan ever heard of get set in typescript? `{{sum}}` is the correct syntax.

Comment: sum is not a variable, here it is a function , as you say i am not an expert

Comment: @Sajeetharan It's a getter. The syntax is correct (although the value being computed is not).

Comment: @JBNizet i am not talking about the syntax, just the expression he used on the template which wont get computed

Comment: I added the demo for you guys to check out, maybe you guy should take a look at the change detection mechanism.

Comment: Yes, you are talking about the syntax. I quote: *it should be {{sum()}}*.

Comment: btw i am not downvoting you

Comment: @JBNizet okay, I'm giving the most important information about the typescript getter and that can help the owner of the question to figure out himself. Anyway, I updated my answer. Okay?

Comment: @Envil I already upvoted your answer (and removed my previous comment since you fixed the code).

Comment: is a GETTER (is a get sum(){..}, other case if was a function mySum(){...}), so {{sum}} is the correct way. really I prefer the first propoused solution {{ticket.child*5 + ticket.adult*15}}

Comment: @Eliseo I think the question owner has some reason to ask for this. With the getter, he can use it in both the template and the typescript code without any pain, and this doesn't decrease the performance at all.

Comment: @Envil Thank you so much! I used this and it works perfectly, and this seems like a really useful way, thank you for the reply!

Comment: @geteds you're welcome. If you think this's the correct answer, please mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Eliseo The first proposed solution is great, but I also would like to know what to do in case I have to repeat it, or if its a long calculation, I'm new to all this, so this curious haha

Answer (score 1):

As JBNizet said, for semantic and possibly functional reasons you should avoid using `<input>` for displaying output. Thus you can rewrite your code like this:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="ticket.adult" name="adult">
<p>{{ ticket.adult*15 }}</p>

<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="ticket.child" name="child">
<p>{{ ticket.child*5 }}</p>


<p>Ticket Price: {{ ticket.adult * 15 + ticket.child * 5 }}</p>
```

However, you probably want to avoid rewriting your adult / child multipliers more than once simply to avoid duplication and also in case they change. My recommended solution in this case would be to use pipes since your calculation is deterministic.

```
@Pipe({ name: 'price' })
export class PricePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(amount, type) {
    let multiplier = 0; // perhaps throw an error or set a sane default
    switch (type) {
      case 'adult':
        multiplier = 15;
      case 'child':
        multiplier = 5;
    }

    return amount * multiplier;
  }
}
```

Now you could use it like:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="ticket.adult" name="adult">
<p>{{ ticket.adult | price:'adult' }}</p>

<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="ticket.child" name="child">
<p>{{ ticket.child | price:'child' }}</p>


<p>Ticket Price: {{ (ticket.adult | price:'adult') + (ticket.child | price:'child') }}</p>
```

Now you can keep the multipliers in one spot and even add other kinds of multipliers later on if you need to. You could even possibly refactor your code to iterate over `'adult'` and `'child'` properties to display the prices rather than hard coding the `.adult` and `.child` values.

Comment: What if we want to access the `sum` in the ts code?

Comment: You can inject pipes too

Comment: Yeah, I know, I mean this approach works but too cumbersome.

Comment: What is cumbersome about it?

Comment: 1. You have to create the pipe, it takes some time. 2. Then in the ts code you need to inject it and call the pipe, not quite elegant to me.

Comment: I don't see why that's cumbersome -- if you wanted to reuse a function for multiple components you would have to set a property on each component for that function whereas you can just use the pipe in the template. If you really needed to inject the pipe you would probably be better off using a service and doing the calculation ahead of time anyway. I also don't see why injecting things is inelegant. Also with your solution you're still doing the multiplication in two spots -- once in the template and once in `sum`.

Comment: @ExplosionPills. Personally I don't like pipes to create an expecific function. It's innecesary complex a simple function {{totalPrice('child',ticket.child)}} and {{totalPrice('adult',ticket.adult)}} also make the work